# Redux-toolkit: how to set fetched data to redux slice's state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

Is there a way to set fetched data to Redux state inside of reducer file itself? I want my 'videoList' and 'showVideos' to be equal to fetched data on first render.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from 'axios'

const VIDEOS_API = 'http://localhost:3001/api'

export const fetchVideos = createAsyncThunk('videos/fetchVideos', async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(VIDEOS_API)
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message
    }
})

const initialString = '';

export const videosSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'videos',
    initialState: {
        videoList: [],
        showVideos: [],
        status: 'idle',
        videoCategories: categories,
        watchLaterList: [],
        searchVideo: initialString,
    }
})
```

I've only tried to set it through component, where data is being rendered. I added this reducer:

```
reducers: {
        setInitialVideos: (state, action) => {
            state.showVideos = action.payload;
            state.videoList = action.payload;
        }
   }
```

And used it like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(status === 'idle') {
      const response = dispatch(fetchVideos())
      dispatch(setInitialVideos(response))
    }
  }, [status])
```

And got an error: 'A non-serializable value was detected in the state'.

The data I am fetching is array of objects equivalent to this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Punic wars",
        "thumbnail": "https://www.mindrevolt.org/images/posts/what-if-carthage-won-the-punic-wars-the-world-we-know-today-would-be-totally-different.jpg",
        "description": "The Punic Wars was a series of wars between 264 and 146 BC that were fought between Rome and Carthage....",
        "category": ["rome"], 
        "likes": 451,
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "punic-wars",
        "date": "10-22-2022",
        "source": "url",
        "comments": []
    },
    {...}
]
```

What would be a correct way to set fetched data to slice's state?

Comment: You just need dispatch `fetchVideos` inside useEffect. Just have this line `dispatch(fetchVideos())` in useEffect and remove all other lines and if condition. Also remove `status` from useEffect dependency array. Since you are using async thunk, move your reducer function inside `extraReducers`. You can read the documentation [Async Requests With createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#async-requests-with-createasyncthunk)